# App keeps restarting iphone on ios 10

Tags: ios, swift

Let me go straight to the problem . My app makes os restarts only on iOS 10 devices . I have no idea why this happens since no crash happens and memory and cpu usage is normal . This happens occasionally

The app is written with swift 2.3 and this strange problem happens only to iOS 10 devices .

This happens on both debugging and release environment on app store . Since no crash happens so i dont know much details !

Regards

Comment: Please describe your setup and your issue more detailed. What kind of target ans such. Does this happen only while debugging or also in release configuration without USB connection ...

Comment: @shallowThought this happens on both conditions on some ios 10 devices

Comment: Does it happen on the iOS 10 simulators or only physical devices?

Comment: @TommyBs physical devices

Comment: This even happens when app is closed . I think this is an os related problem but how can i fix it because not all the apps cause os to crash

Comment: Thinking outside of the box... Does the device(s) restart even if the app is deleted from it?  Are you able to reset things? Maybe even reinstall the OS? I'm wondering how you can be sure it's **your** app that's the cause.

Comment: Yes when they uninstall the app everything will be fine ! That's why its very strange for me . I think maybe my app binaries have which is written with swift 2.3 have some conflicts with ios 10 so that might cause this happen . @dfd

Answer (score -1):

This is the bug !

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61995

It is LocalNotification bug . which is still open and the workaround is scheduling less than 30 UILocalNotifications . Hope apple fix this soon .